# iOS7 jpg decompression issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios7

This could be either a retina display issue or an iOS7 issue, but all of my retina displays are running iOS7, so I have no way of testing operating system differences at the moment.

When I load a jpg on an iPad2 running 6.1.3 it looks perfect, just as I would expect.  When I load the same image (using the same code) on the iPad3 or 4 running 7.0.2 I get blue jitters around all of the orange text.  I also get blue lines in other locations around colored text.  Is there a setting that I can change in the decompression of jpgs?  When I change to using PNG's it looks perfect on both screens, but I this is in a very large tilinglayer and I don't want to double the size of my app because of this.

The code I am using to create the UIImages:
`[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]`

Here is the original image that I am trying to load:

[image]

Here is the retina screen

[image: retina]

Here is the retina screen using png's instead of jpg's

[image]

And here is the retina screen in the simulator:

[image]

And here is the iPad 2 (double size just to show 1 to 1 scaling)

[image]

Now looking at them all at the same scale, the iPad2 and retina simulator makes it look better than the original image, but the retina screen still adds in interesting lowlights that I need to get rid of.  This is apparently only an issue on the device, not the identical setup in simulator.

Comment: Do you have retina images in your project? Images will be automatically scaled (an appear blurry) unless you have the @2x images in your application. iOS can't just magically double the resolution of images without blurriness.

Comment: I do not, but blurry is not the issue.  Discoloration is the issue.

Comment: discolorisation and blurryness both comes from a lower resolution (the blue might come from antialiasing orange text pixels  to brown background)

Comment: @AlexWien That makes perfect sense, but is there any way to fix it other than getting a higher resolution initial image (I can't at the moment, it's a capture from another piece of software)?  But I'm also still confused on why this would not show up on retina simulator, only retina device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original has bad quality don't expect that any system will improve the original image, although for luck it happenend on the simualotor.

Two solutions:
1) provide a high quality image for retina (@2x)
2) Use photoshop to make the image double size, and hope that photoshop use better algorithms.
Then save as (@2x)

Comment: I don't expect anything to get better.  I expect when I blow up an image to the exact same size that it should look pretty darn close.  If you look at the "R"s in my example above I have no idea where the blue came from (it didn't just show up, it replaced the orange).

Comment: Also, this issue does not happen with identically sized PNG's.  So it's definitely an issue with the jpg decompression on the device.

Comment: jgs only look good in 1:1, if you blow up further than 1:1, then they look as good as the hardware estimates it. The pixesl are misssing, the system cannot know how to fill them. I would expect that  they look equal on ipad and iPhone, but the blow up is done in hardware, so it may depend on the graphics processor used. And maybe on th eoptions that Apple set internal

Comment: jpg is a lossy decompression, png not, this can have an influence.  Apple recomends to use png.

Comment: Actually iPhone retina looks perfect.  It's only a problem on the iPad retina (possibly only iOS7).  I understand your point, but it's just too localized for my liking.  If I can't find anything soon I will mark you as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add what solved my problem here, but mark the other answer as correct because he at least tried to help and was knowledgable about the topic.

I restored the iPad to the latest firmware and iOS (even though it already was running the latest) and the problem went away.  I have another iPad that was exhibiting the same problem, so I will see if reflashing it solves the problem on it as well.